# PowerShell try-catch exit loop before second try occurs

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm trying to loop a list of users where it is unknown if it contains English or Swedish and in addition to this check I need to know if there is an account called "CMG*" before executing the main task.

The problem is that my first 'Try' runs the lines as expected but the second one is ignored, so it apparently exit the loop on 'continue' it seems.

Can you not have 2 sets of 'Try-Catch' inside an 'if' statement?

What I have tried is to flip the two sets of 'Try-Catch' and it results in whatever is first in the loop execute and the bottom one is ignored.

```
foreach($User in $Users){

    if($User."ADattribute"){

        try {
            if(!(Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($User.UserPrincipalName):\Calendar" | Where-Object User -like 'CMG*')){

                Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($User.UserPrincipalName):\Calendar" -User <SecretUser> -AccessRights Reviewer
            }

        continue
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] {

            Write-Host ":\Calendar could not be found"          
        }

        try {
            if(!(Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($User.UserPrincipalName):\Kalender" | Where-Object User -like 'CMG*')){

                Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($User.UserPrincipalName):\Kalender" -User <SecretUser> -AccessRights Reviewer
            }

        continue
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] {

            Write-Host ":\Kalender could not be found."          
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the function of the keyword **continue**. When executing the continue keyword, the current iteration stops and it continues with the next iteration. So I think if you remove the continue keyword(s) that your script will work as excepted.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-looping-the-continue-statement/

Comment: Thanks! The document helped me understand it well and it also makes me want to add the 'continue' on the first section since if if doesn't throw an excepting the second 'try' is irrelevant. 
However, it seems the 'catch' parts are not working for me at all even when specifying the exception...

Comment: I just figured out the 'catch' problem and it was fixed by adding "-ErrorAction Stop" after the mailbox lines!